# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between analog and digital clock, date, and day of the week

Tags: shortcut, menu-bar, shortcut-menu

Is there a way to create a shortcut so that I can display the clock differently? I would like to have the option for the menu bar to show only the analog clock without the date or the day of the week:

> System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Clock Menu Bar > Time Options:
> Digital

And I would like to be able to switch to:

```
System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Clock Menu Bar > 
   Date Options: Show the day of the week
                 Show the date
   Time Options: Digital
```

I tried to create a shortcut by going to

> System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

However, I was not successful with figuring out what I need to change. For an App, I chose System Preferences, but choosing a shortcut for "Show the day of the week" did not work. I tried other ideas, but so far no luck. Any suggestions?